# Analysing objects that belong to different fact tables (different contexts)

Tags: business-objects

My universe has gotten bigger; there are now 8 fact tables and around 20 dimensions.

Because I have 8 fact tables, I defined 8 contexts. My assumption is that it is only possible to take objects that belong to a speciic context in order to analyse exactly those objects in **one** report.

Conversely, that should mean, that it is **not** possible to take objects that belong to different fact tables (different contexts), and analyse them in **one** report (by *one report* I refer to one **table**).

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 2):

First some terminology; it might sound like nitpicking, but it avoids confusion:

- *Document* — A single Web Intelligence document which can consist of multiple reports and data providers
- *Data provider* — A collection of universe objects (dimensions, measures, details, …). This may result in one or more SQL statements when defined on a relational source.
- *Report* — Represented as a *tab* (at the bottom) within a Web Intelligence document (comparable to a Excel worksheet vs Excel Workbook). A report can contain data from any and all data providers defined in the same document.

You can specify in the parameters of your data foundation whether or not to allow the selection of multiple contexts in the same data provider. If you allow this, selecting from multiple contexts in the same data provider will result in (at least) 1 SQL statement for each of those contexts.

If you do not allow selection of objects from multiple contexts, you will receive an error message stating *Incompatible objects* when you try to refresh a data provider that violates this.

See also [Universe Design Tool User Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41_universe_design_tool_en.pdf) - paragraph 5.4.7 *How do Contexts Affect Queries?* and specifically paragraph 5.4.7.3 *Incompatible queries*.

For the parameter to define the context behaviour, see [Information Design Tool User Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41_info_design_tool_en.pdf), paragraph 10.18 *About data foundation properties*. The option is called *Multiple SQL statements for each context*.

Comment: Hi Kristof! Thanks for the important info. However, let's keep our eyes 'on-the-ball'. The question was - what happens when objects from different contexts are selected. Example: In a simplified data model with 2 fact tables there are 2 contexts. For example, a end-user decides to select following objects: o1, o2, c13, c24, f15, f26.
Here objects o1 and o2 belong to BOTH contexts, object c12 belongs only to the first context, object c24 belongs only to the second context, object f15 belongs to the first object and first fact table, object f26 belongs to the second object in second fact table

Comment: Now, supose that multiple contexts are allowed, the question is - what happens? My assumption is the following: We get 2 results: result 1 and result 2. In result one the end user sees the following objects (objects that belong to the first context): o1, o2, c13, f15. Furthermore, result 2 shows the following objects: o1,o2, c24, f26. Is that correct? (these 2 results will be represented in two different tables, and each tables is generated with different SQL statement. Is this correct as well?)

Answer (score 0):

To answer briefly, YES it is possible to combine objects from different contexts in a single block (table or graph) and therefore also in the same report or document (refer to Kristof's clear explanation above of the different components of a WebI Document).

So NO, your assumption is not correct -- *but*, it depends on what kind of objects you are combining.  In general, your dimensions will be shared across multiple contexts, while your measures will specific to a single context.  When you build a data provider which uses multiple contexts, the common dimensions will be compatible with all of the measures, and all of the above can be displayed in the same block. Dimensions which are not shared are more complicated: A dimension only available in context A cannot be combined with a dimension only available in context B.

When you think about it (and I encourage you to play around with it and see how it works), it makes sense: as long as the dimensions are shared, you are comparing all your measures to the same thing, whether or not the underlying SQL is separated by contexts or not.

Comment: thx for your reply emilys. The whole point of my question was actually not about combining dimensions, but about combining measures (comming from different fact tables). I have noticed that when I take two measures from different fact tables, then I get two different reports. Since the end-user is repeatedly asking that he wants to compare multiple measures from different fact tables, I am not sure what to answer him. Maybe you already answerd it, but can you please say one more time, if multiple measures from different fact tables can exist in one report table?

Comment: If all the dimensions are shared, you can absolutely place multiple measures from different fact tables in one report block (by default in 4.1, WebI generates one table; may be different in 3.1, but even if it isn't generated by default you can drag and drop the objects together).  If you are having any trouble getting this to work, chances are there's a problem with the definition of your measures (particularly the projection function)